# Wildcard Subdomain In SpringBoot For my Mac

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot, tomcat, wildcard-subdomain

I am creating a web application in which there will be multiple subdomain. Each client will be having its own subdomain. Each subdomain will have individual database. For example I am having a client abc, then it will have subdomain as **abc.mydomain.com** and its database name will be **abc**.

Now this application is created in spring boot. Here I want to configure wildcard subdomain. So how can I configure it in spring boot. For this, I had tried few solution.

I had changed my /etc/hosts and added an domain name entry in it as below

`127.0.0.1    www.mydomain.com`

But now I want subdomain in this. How can I do it.

I had seen somewhere that I need to configure server.xml of tomcat. In server.xml I had added below line.

```
<Host name="www.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true"
autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>*.mydomain.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

Can you please help me with this. Also let me know incase you need more details in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After been working for multiple days I came to a solution for this question. As I was working for wildcard subdomain in localhost. Thus for this I need to use an external software called **dnsmasq**, I had executed following commands to install **dnsmasq** in my laptop.

`brew install dnsmasq`

After installing dnsmasq in my laptop I need to to configure it. For this I have to update the dnsmasq. For my case it is located at

`/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

In this file I have to add few lines to configure wildcard subdomain. Lines are as below.

```
# Route all *.mydomain.com addresses to localhost
address=/mydomain.com/127.0.0.1
# Don't read /etc/resolv.conf or any other configuration files.
no-resolv
# Never forward plain names (without a dot or domain part)
domain-needed
# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv
```

Next I need to restart my dnsmasq service. Command for it is as below.

`sudo brew services start dnsmasq`

Finally you need to create a file **mydomain.com** at /etc/resolver (Create folder resolver if not exists). Add below line in **mydomain.com** file.

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

This is the complete configuration for setting up swildcard subdomain in your mac os.

For reference you can follow **[this link](https://maximilianschmitt.me/posts/local-subdomains-dnsmasq-caddy/)**